# Using $request.session.setAttribute to store a dropdown's setting

Tags: jsp, velocity

I'm trying to store a drop-down's setting that's controlling how many items to display in a roster. How do I go about doing this? The dropdown is using onChange to sort the results of the roster.

Comment: It's just a list of users, items etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do Velocity, so here's a JSP/Servlet-targeted answer. I suppose you're using Servlets as well, as Velocity is actually a templating engine and does nothing to control/preprocess/postprocess requests.

So you want to retain certain data in the subsequent requests? There are basically two ways to achieve this.

1. Retain the value for the subsequent request in a hidden input element. E.g.

   ```
   <form action="servlet" method="post">
       <select name="itemcount" onchange="submit()">
           <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>
       </select>
   </form>
   ```

   and then in the form of the next request:

   ```
   <form action="servlet" method="post">
       <select name="sortfield" onchange="submit()">
           <option>col1</option><option>col2</option><option>col3</option>
       </select>
       <input type="hidden" name="itemcount" value="${param.itemcount}">
   </form>
   ```

   The `${param.itemcount}` basically returns `request.getParameter("itemcount")`. When stored in a hidden input element you see nothing, but it will be as well available by `request.getParameter("itemcount")` in the next request.
2. Store the value in session. E.g. inside the servlet:

   ```
   Integer itemcount = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("itemcount"));
   request.getSession().setAttribute("itemcount", itemcount);
   ```

   so that you can access it in any servlet running in the same session as follows whenever needed:

   ```
   Integer itemcount = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("itemcount");
   ```

   But this has a major caveat: this may cause "wtf?" experiences when the user has multiple windows open inside the same session and selects a different itemcount in the both windows. The last selected value in window A would be reflected into window B!

I think it's obvious that you should keep request scoped data in the request scope, so way 1 is more preferred. Use the session *only* for session scoped data.

Comment: BalusC, thanks for answer man. I tried to implement this, and it yieled no results. I'm fairly new to this. I took over a site, and it's in velocity etc. Do you think I could use 
$request.session.setAttribute

and then request the session through getAttribute? Thanks again.